# FFmpeg - help me about "process video (cut, overlay) one command"

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have one video, now i am using this to work. I wonder can I use it in one command?

I mean can do it with a period of 120 seccond video without cut process.

- Strim video into 120 second video
- Do PTS and overlay with every 120 second video
- Merge them into one.

  for %%t in ("input*.*") DO ffmpeg -y  -i "%%t" -s 854x480 -c copy -map 0 -segment_time 00:120 -f segment "cut%%04d.mp4"

  for %%t in ("cut*.mp4") DO ffmpeg  -y  -i "%%t" -i "%%t" -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=PTS/1.4,scale=854x480[v1];[1:v]setpts=PTS/1,scale=854x480[v2];[v2]setpts=PTS/1.2[v3];[v1][v3]overlay=shortest=1:enable='lt(mod(t,8),6)*gte(t,10)';[0:a]atempo=1" -threads 8 -preset ultrafast "temp%%~nt.mp4"

  for %%f in (temp*mp4) do (
  echo file '%%f' >> list.txt
  )
  ffmpeg  -f concat -safe 0 -i list.txt -c copy "Output\Done.mp4"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I mean exactly is: I have a long video, I trim video into many short video which have duration = 120 second then use above code to rend video (120 second) and merge them again into long video. I want to apply this code for long video directly without trim long video into many 120 second.